# Load second dropdown based on first - JQuery Dialog

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I need to update my second drop down list from database according to the value selected from first drop down list in the Jquery dialog.

**ASPX**

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upnl" OnLoad="upnl_Load" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<ContentTemplate>
<div id="dv" style="display: none;" title="Tile">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Parent</td>
        <td>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDialog1" runat="server" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Child</td>
        <td>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDialog2" runat="server" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div >
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**JQuery**

```
function EditBookingDialog() {
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        $("#dvEditBooking").dialog({
            draggable: true,
            modal: true,
            width: 500,
            height: 400
            ,
            open: function (type, data) {
                $("#<%= ddlDialog1.ClientID %>").change(function () {
                    __doPostBack('<%= upnl.ClientID %>', "DialogOnChange");
                });
            }
        });
    });
}
```

**Code behind**

```
protected void upnl_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (arg.ToString().IndexOf("DialogOnChange") > -1)
{
    // Here ddlDialog1.SelectedValue is always " ", Even I get a data set of values,ddlDialog2 is not populated with new values 
    ddlDialog2.DataSource = objMngr.GetData(ddlDialog1.SelectedValue);
    ddlDialog2.DataValueField = "Id";
    ddlDialog2.DataTextField = "name";
    ddlDialog2.DataBind();
}
 upnl.Update();
}
```

Problem here is, 
How to Populate second drop down list(ddlDialog2) upon value change in the first drop down list.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the Server side change event of the 1st dropdown.
Modify the html of 1st drop down as follows.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDialog1" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="upnl_Load()" />
```

remove jquery change and manually calling _do postback

```
    $("#<%= ddlDialog1.ClientID %>").change(function () {

          $.ajax(function{
          url: "/YourPage.aspx"
          type:"POST"
          data:{"FirstDropDownValue" : $(this).val() }
          success:function(msg){
            //bind your second dropdown here.
            if(msg.d != null)
             {

      // Looping over list
        $.each(msg.d, function (index, value) {
            $("#ddlDialog1").append($("<option>   </option>").val(value["Id"]).html(value["name"]));

             });
           }

    });
```

Update the server side method as follows

```
[WebMethod]
public static List<Myclass> void upnl_Load( string FirstDropDownValue)
{
  if (FirstDropDownValue != "-1")
  {
    return objMngr.GetData(FirstDropDownValue);
  }

  upnl.Update();
}
```

Comment: I think you don't fully understand my question.

Comment: do want to load the 2nd dropdown  using jquery ?

Comment: Yes. please see is there any improvements needed for my jquery calls.

Comment: you need to do ajax call to your method and bind the 2nd dropdown in jquery see the sample code.
more help: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/AJAX-Cascading-DropDownList-using-jQuery-in-ASP.Net.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your idea, I will try it. Can you able to explain why I can't populate the second drop down with my implementation.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37033/discussion-between-sudhansu63-and-roshe)

Comment: I tried your solution as well and no luck. This will work on forms not for Jquery dialogs. If you can try my scenario and update me. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: jQuery dialog is a div and it comes inside the form. so this should work. Any console error ?